# Django Rest Framework application with gunicorn deployment

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, deployment, gunicorn

I have a django rest framework application that is using class style views.

My deployment is simple: ***gunicorn --workers=4 application_name.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000***

The issue is that it takes only 4 requests at a time. If I send 20 requests concurrently, it processes them in groups of 4 at a time.

What do I have to do so that it processes all 20 requests concurrently?

Comment: I have tried using worker-class=gevent but that gives another error, You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async. while accessing the django orm. Also I could see DRF doesnt support async views anyway.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [gunicorn docs](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html#threads), you need to set `threads` parameter in order to process requests concurrently, for example,

> gunicorn --workers=4 --threads=10 application_name.wsgi -b
> 0.0.0.0:8000

will bring up 4 workers and each worker has 10 threads to process the requests.

Comment: that would still solve at max 40 concurrent requests. I've seen Projects with gunicorn --workers=5 --worker-class=gevent --worker-connections=100 but they are on Python 3.6 & as soon as they are moved to higher version of Python. They throw the error You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async. while accessing the django orm